# How can hashset.contains be O(1) with this implementation?

Tags: c#, .net-core, time-complexity, hashset

HashSet.Contains implementation in .Net is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if this hashset contains the item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">item to check for containment</param>
    /// <returns>true if item contained; false if not</returns>
    public bool Contains(T item) {
        if (m_buckets != null) {
            int hashCode = InternalGetHashCode(item);
            // see note at "HashSet" level describing why "- 1" appears in for loop
            for (int i = m_buckets[hashCode % m_buckets.Length] - 1; i >= 0; i = m_slots[i].next) {
                if (m_slots[i].hashCode == hashCode && m_comparer.Equals(m_slots[i].value, item)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        // either m_buckets is null or wasn't found
        return false;
    }
```

And I read in a lot of places "search complexity in hashset is O(1)". How?
Then why does that for-loop exist?

Edit: .net reference link: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs

Comment: Maybe there is a constant number of buckets?

Comment: Try read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation - O(1) doesn't mean 1 operation, it means independent of the number of source objects. If the loop went from 0 to [number of elements in hashset], then it would be O(N)

Comment: Provide a source of this implementation. Is this from .NET Framework ReferenceSource, or from .NET Core?

Comment: @Milney ... I know complexity is no numer of operations. But I'm asking for the loop. Always the m_buckets.Length > 1 & condition not success the complexity will not be O(1).

Comment: @V0ldek https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs

Comment: This is how all hash sets and dictionaries behave. What you see is rehashing, this usually don't happen, but can happen at really large collections or bad hashing of object. O(1) in hashing is usually means a "Median" value, if your hashing is bad (always return 123 for multiple objects) or collection is too big - you will get O(N)

Comment: @eocron This doesn't edit in any way the hash. Why do you say "rehash"?

Comment: You need to look into how a hash set handles collisions. I'm not sure which implementation this is but it looks like if there is a collision(different item with same hash) the set will put the new item in m_slots[i].next. If theres still an item collision at that location it will keep going till there isnt a collision.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper rehashing doesn't mean you need to edit something, it means you calculate hash for consequitive collisions. Contains in this case just jumping over collision buckets.

Comment: @themiDdlest In other words, the buckets can have more than one slot? Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Then we can be more specific: in general search is O(1), but if we have collisions we'll have O(<= k) with k the number of elements with same hash (obviously 1<k<n). Isn't it?

Comment: `O(1)` is the best case, worst case can be `O(n)`, if you have all items under the same hash value, located in one bucket. Actually, the worst case isn't really possible in practical, but you should know that in worst case you can go through all items

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski read my just before comment, but thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The classic implementation of a hash table works by assigning elements to one of a number of buckets, based on the hash of the element. [If the hashing was perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), i.e. no two elements had the same hash, then we'd be living in a perfectly perfect world where we wouldn't need to care about anything - any lookup would be O(1) *always*, because we'd only need to compute the hash, get the bucket and say if something is inside.

We're not living in a perfectly perfect world. First off, consider string hashing. In .NET, there are (2^16)^n possible strings of length `n`; `GetHashCode` returns an `int`, and there are 2^32 possible values of `int`. That's exactly enough to hash every string of length 2 to a unique `int`, but if we want strings longer than that, **there must exist two different values that give the same hash - this is called a collision**. Also, we don't want to maintain 2^32 buckets at all times anyway. The usual way of dealing with that is to take the hashcode and compute its value modulo the number of buckets to determine the bucket's number<sup>1</sup>. So, the takeaway is - **we need to allow for collisions**.

The referenced [.NET Framework implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs) uses the simplest way of dealing with collisions - [**every bucket holds a linked list of all objects that result in the particular hash**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining). You add object `A`, it's assigned to a bucket `i`. You add object `B`, it has the same hash, so it's added to the list in bucket `i` right after `A`. Now if you lookup for any element, you need to traverse the list of all objects and call the actual `Equals` method to find out if that thing is actually the one you're looking for. That explains the for loop - **in the worst case you *have to* go through the entire list**.

Okay, so how "search complexity in hashset is O(1)"? **It's not. The worst case complexity is proportional to the number of items. It's O(1) *on average*.**<sup>2</sup> If all objects fall to the same bucket, asking for the elements at the end of the list (or for ones that are not in the structure but would fall into the same bucket) *will* be O(n).

So what do people mean by "it's O(1) on average"? The structure monitors how many objects are there proportional to the number of buckets and if that exceeds some threshold, called the load factor, it resizes. It's easy to see that this makes the average lookup time proportional to the load factor.

That's why it's important for hash functions to be *uniform*, meaning that the probability that two randomly chosen different objects get the same `int` assigned is 1/2^32<sup>3</sup>. That keeps the distribution of objects in a hash table uniform, so we avoid pathological cases where one bucket contains a huge number of items.

Note that if you know the hash function and the algorithm used by the hash table, you can force such a pathological case and O(n) lookups. If a server takes inputs from a user and stores them in a hash table, an attacker knowing the hash function and the hash table implementations could use this as a vector for a DDoS attack. [There are ways of dealing with that too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing). Treat this as a demonstration that yes, the worst case can be O(n) and that people are generally aware of that.

There are dozens of other, more complicated ways hash tables can be implemented. If you're interested you need to research on your own. Since lookup structures are so commonplace in computer science, people have come up with all sorts of crazy optimisations that minimise not only the theoretical number of operations, but also things like CPU cache misses.

---

[1] That's exactly what's happening in the statement `int i = m_buckets[hashCode % m_buckets.Length] - 1`

[2] At least the ones using naive chaining are not. [There exist hash tables with worst-case constant time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing). But usually they're worse in practice compared to the theoretically (in regards to time complexity) slower implementations, mainly due to CPU cache misses.

[3] I'm assuming the domain of possible hashes is the set of all `int`s, so there are 2^32 of them, but everything I wrote generalises to any other non-empty, finite set of values.

Comment: I reread the answer 8 months later, and man, it's so pleasant read such a good answer. I wish I could vote up this answer again.