# C# best approach to check a value is exist in a List Several times

Tags: c#, search

I have list of integers and I want to know a value exist in my list Several times.

What is the best approach to do this?

catching data using `LookUp` or `dictionary` or `HashMap`  or ...?

Example:

```
List<int> samples = {5,4,6,2,1}
// if(2 exist in samples) do something ...
// if(3 exist in samples) do something ...
// if(5 exist in samples) do something ...
// if(8 exist in samples) do something ...
// if(13 exist in samples) do something ...
// if ....
```

Comment: "several times" - will the contents of the list change in between tests?

Comment: You could use a `HashSet<int>`, but you might get a more meaningful answer with a bit of extra detail/context.

Comment: no ,contents of list not changed

Comment: easiest way is probably just to use .Contains({item})
if (samples.Contains(2)){ do something }

Comment: "best" is contextual; how many times is "several times"? a dozen: just use `Contains`. Lots and lots of times, often in a tight loop? You'd want an optimized data structure such as `HashSet<T>`, or *at a minimum* you'd want to sort it and check with binomial search. Of course, it also depends on the real number of values; if it is *really* just 1,2,4,5,6 - just use a `switch` block: you only need to optimize for larger numbers of test cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store them in [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0) and check whether value exists with `O(1)`:

```
var unique = new HashSet<int>(){ 5,4,6,2,1};
var hasValue = unique.Contains(1);
```

and then just check:

```
if (unique.Contains(2)) 
    // do something ...
```

In addition, `HashSet<T>` prevents storing duplicates, so it is extremely fast.

**UPDATE:**

`List<T>`  will search with O(N). Why? Because Big O Notation should consider the worst case of time complexity. Let's imagine we have the following list:

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 5, 4, 6, 2, 1 };
```

and we want to find number `1`. So `Contains()` method of `List<T>` has to iterate the whole array until it finds number `1`. So we have `O(N)`.

`LinkedList<T>` will search with O(N). Why? The reason is the same like in `List<T>`. However, `LinkedList<T>` does not have an array under the hood, it has a class which has a pointer to next element and next element has pointer to the next element and so on. We have to iterate all elements to find an item.

`HashSet<T>` will search with O(1). Why? The reason is `HashSet<T>` under the hood will not iterate through array. It will run internal method `InternalGetHashCode` which returns position of number in array. [You can see the source code here.](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs)

In addition, there is a very nice answer about [How can hashset.contains be O(1) with this implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671962/how-can-hashset-contains-be-o1-with-this-implementation)

Comment: Thanks @stepUp, Can you tell me why dose not suggest Dictionary? or something other?

Comment: @Amir133 because a dictionary stores a key/value pair, and you only need a key here - not a value, which `HashSet<T>` can do for you

Comment: @Amir133 `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can throw exceptions if there is already key that you want to add. Moreover, with `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you have to store `TValue`, but it is not necessary to you.

Comment: @Amir133 `List<T>` and `LinkedList<T>` will search with `O(N)`

Comment: Thanks @StepUp ,Your answer is enough for me, but if possible, give more explanations to the viewers.

Comment: @StepUp Thanks alot

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you mean by best. If you are using a list, you could use the Exists() method.

```
if(samples.Exists(value => value == valueToCheck)){
    //Do work
}
```

Comment: can tell me order of `Exists`

Comment: That isn't how `Exists` works. It expects a `Predicate<T>`, not a value.

Comment: Searching a list is inefficient. Unless you have a toy application, you should not use a data structure with O(n) time complexity, i.e., an array (or the dynamic version, a list) to do lookups.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: Even with the update, just use `Contains()`... They're both O(n). `Exists()` doesn't gain you anything here other than just being more complicated when used on a simple `List<int>`. Obviously a list shouldn't even be used here, but that's a different argument.